# как спарсить значение aqi с сайта?

Tags: python, парсер, web-scraping

в парсинге я полный ноль но смотря гайды в интернете у меня получалось парсить данные с сайта но не в этот раз. есть сайт aqicn.org и с него надо спарсить значение aqi но у меня никак не получается это сделать.

https://aqicn.org/station/kazakhstan/almaty/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE/ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно спарсить выделенный синем значение

вот код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


url = 'https://aqicn.org/station/kazakhstan/almaty/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE/ru/'

response = requests.get(url)

html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div', class_ = "station-specie-aqi"))
```

Comment: почему не получается? какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: на сайте контент подгружается динамически, попробуйте использовать Selenium

Comment: там сверху этого класса есть другой класс когда я его пишу он показывает мне все что есть до div id station data а дальше ничего вообще ничего